# After updating to entity framework 6 my ajax call is not working

Tags: c#, ajax, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am making a wedding website. After realizing I needed to update to entity framework 6 my Controller stopped working. I am using ajax call to see if user has allready logged in and then he doesn't need to log in each time he/she has been away.

I get blablabla.Table does not contain a defintion for "LoggedIn"

This worked before I updated to entityframework 6..... why doesn't it work now?

This is my code

Controller:

```
        public ActionResult Login(Table u)
        {
            // this action is for handle post (login)
            if (ModelState.IsValid) // this is check validity
            {
                using (LoginEntities dc = new LoginEntities())
                {
                    var v = dc.Tables.Where(a => a.Username.Equals(u.Username) && a.PassWord.Equals(u.PassWord)).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (v != null)
                    {
                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(u.Username, true);
                        u.LoggedIn = true;
                        return Json(u);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        u.LoggedIn = false;
                        u.Message = "You have entered the wrong password, please try again!";
                        return Json(u);



                    }
                }
            }
            return View(u);
        }
    }

}
```

Script:

```
$("#LoginForm").submit(function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    var url = $(event.target).attr("action");
    //var username = $("#Username");
    var model = $(event.target).serialize();
    //console.log(model);
    console.log(url);
    $.ajax({

        url: url,
        data: model,
        type:"POST",
        success: function (response) {
            console.log("bla");
            if (response.LoggedIn) { window.location = "/Home/Index" } else
            { alert(response.Message); }
        }

    });

});
```

Class:

```
    public partial class Table
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string PassWord { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the `Table` class?

Comment: Please edit your post rather than comment. Also, that is your context, not the `Table` entity.

Comment: Sorry I am totaly confused

Comment: Does the answer help?

Comment: Yes! Thanks! I need to change the name of the project!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you have this line:

```
u.LoggedIn = true;
```

The variable `u` is of type `Table` that has no property called `LoggedIn`. The error is nothing to do with entity framework.

`Table` is a partial class though so may have been extended somewhere else previously.